# Excel Personal Macro Workbook reference Book1

Tags: vba, excel

I've finally figured out why my code was crashing. I have this set up as part of my Personal Macro Workbook so when I open a default Book1 I can run it. However, the issue is that since it's running the macro from the PMW the "Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)" is crashing.

How can I make it that the code below running from the PMW would copy the sheets into the default Book1?

Original code below;

```
Sub GetSheets()
Application.AutoRecover.Enabled = False
LInput:
     PL = Application.InputBox("Threshold Report Path", "", "C:\Users\")
      Path = PL
      Filename = Dir(Path & "*.csv")
        Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
           For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
           Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
           Workbooks(Filename).Close
           Filename = Dir()
        Loop

      End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook with the macro.

You can refer to it by name:

```
    Sheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Foo").Sheets(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of the Personal Macro Workbook; it shouldn't be auto-running anything. It's not a template. It's a place to store macros that you use often, so that instead of copying the macros to different workbooks, you can leave it in one place an run it from there.

I think what you want is a Personal Template that includes the template worksheet already, so nothing needs to be copied every time you create a new document.

Create a workbook, copy the worksheet in manually, and save it as a template.  Avoid auto-run code in the template as well.

See links below for more information.

---

### More information:

**What you are trying to use:**

- Office.com : **[Create and save all your macros in a single workbook](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790)**
- Office.com : **[Create and save all your macros in a single workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790)**

**What you should be using:**

- Office.com : **[Save a workbook as a template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-workbook-as-a-template-58c6625a-2c0b-4446-9689-ad8baec39e1e)**
- Makeuseof : **[How to Quickly Create a Custom Excel Template to Save Time](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/quickly-create-custom-excel-template-save-time/)**